# Copy/Paste from one constantly changing workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a Macro that will take data from a spreadsheet that is constantly updating with varying amounts of data, and paste it into another spreadsheet in a single column without overwrite. The other thing is it is searching for two points, one of those being the bottom, and the other being the value "A1" in the 12th column as the top defining point.

```
Sub Thickness()
'
' Thickness Macro
' Transfer Thickness
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
Windows("data2.xls").Activate

Call FindLast(FinalRow)

Call FindTop(CurVal)



Do While CurVal <= FinalRow
     Windows("data2.xls").Activate
     Cells(CurVal, 8).Copy
     CurVal = CurVal + 1
     Windows("TestMacroProgram.xls").Activate
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
Loop

End Sub

Sub FindLast(FinalRow)
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub

Sub FindTop(CurVal)
    CurVal = FinalRow
    Do While Cells([CurVal], [12]).Value <> "A1"
    CurVal = CurVal - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When I go to run it I keep getting runtime error 1004, application defined or object defined error. I ran the debugger, and it says this line is the problem.

Comment: Do While Cells([CurVal], [12]).Value <> "A1"

Comment: Try: Do While Cells(CurVal, 12).Value <> "A1"

Comment: I tried that and got the same error unfortunately. Is the comparison the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not returning a value from the subs you are calling so when you call `FindTop` the value for `FinalRow` is empty, the same issue is going to happen when you return from `FindTop` because `CurVal` is also empty in the `Thickness` sub.

I'd usually add a global variable if I needed to return something but I'm sure that's frowned upon or I would just bring those subs into the main and not worry about it.  I did do some searching and I believe the code below will work for you and return the correct values.  I wasn't able to finish `Thickness` but I was able to return both values so it should work.  I assume you wanted to return `CurVal` from `FindTop`?

```
Sub Thickness()
'
' Thickness Macro
' Transfer Thickness
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
Windows("data2.xls").Activate

FinalRow = FindLast()

CurVal = FindTop(FinalRow)



Do While CurVal <= FinalRow
     Windows("data2.xls").Activate
     Cells(CurVal, 8).Copy
     CurVal = CurVal + 1
     Windows("TestMacroProgram.xls").Activate
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
Loop

End Sub

Function FindLast()
    FindLast = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function FindTop(FinalRow)
    CurVal = FinalRow
    Do While Cells([CurVal], [12]).Value <> Range("A1").Value
    CurVal = CurVal - 1
    Loop
    FindTop = CurVal
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, I do want to return CurVal. I am still getting an error on the Do While loop. Am I trying to test for something that VBA can't test for.

Comment: The Do While Loop in the FindTop function.

Comment: Also, using the "Locals" window in the VBA editor would allow you to see the variables value in each Sub or Function.

Comment: I figured out how to run the step editor and found my main problem, as it turns out its not recognizing the value A1 in the cell, which is confusing. Is there a better way to define it so it will catch the cell to stop at?

Comment: Do While Cells([CurVal], [12]).Value <> Range("A1").Value

Comment: It keeps running until CurVal hits zero, and then gives the error.

Comment: I figured out a way to make it work, I decided to add a cell to compare to that I hid off to the side of the main sheet, so it would be easier to compare and break. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working.  I'm sure you could do the comparison in VBA but one would need to see the data you are comparing.  In my test workbook it did fine but I was only using manually entered numbers.